# Fraction cached larger than 100%

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following Spark job, some RDD have RDD **fraction cached** more than 100%. How can this be possible? What did I miss? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is because you can have the same partition cached in multiple locations. See [SPARK-4049](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4049) for more details.

EDIT:

I'm wondering if maybe you have [speculative execution](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling) (see `spark.speculation`) set? If you have straggling tasks, they will be relaunched which I believe will duplicate a partition. Also, another useful thing to do might be to call `rdd.toDebugString` which will provide lots of info on an RDD including transformation history and number of cached partitions.

Comment: I didn't call .persist twice on any RDD. What other operation might cause this? Is there a way I can find out which RDD is cached twice? Thanks!

Comment: Looking at your UI, the RDD's that are cached twice have 500 partitions (RDD 19) and 50 partitions (RDD 30). You can programmatically call `rdd.partitions.size` (or `rdd.getNumPartitions()` in pyspark) on each RDD to figure out which RDD is exceeding 100%.